# VSCode view JSON file with colorpicker beside RGB color definition

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using VSCode 1.46.1 on Ubuntu 20.04. Opening two JSON files of some color themes in `~/.vscode/extensions/`. One JSON file has a color picker beside the RGB color code. The other does not. What is the reason? And how to enable/disable the colorpicker?

[image]

Comment: Related but not really an answer to this particular question: [How can I enable the VS Code Color Picker outside of CSS-like scopes?](/q/50622898)