# VS Code color decorators not working consistently

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to see VS Code's color decorators in json files (settings.json, for one) and now it doesn't seem to work consistently anymore.

Strangely, the color decorators and pickers work on *some* json files and not on others.

As an example of the issue here are two screenshots of 2 json files. Both are **identical** (I actually duplicated them) and one shows the decorator and the other doesn't.

Any clue as to why this could be happening?

[image: json with color decorators and picker]

[image: json WITHOUT decorators]

Comment: Related but not really an answer to this particular question: [How can I enable the VS Code Color Picker outside of CSS-like scopes?](/q/50622898). Also, this sounds like a duplicate of [VSCode view JSON file with colorpicker beside RGB color definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62743518/11107541) (unfortunately, no answer there either right now).